# How we can add three js 3D model in Cesium map

Tags: three.js, cesiumjs

I want to add three JS 3D model in Cesium map application but i have not idea how we can do this.

below code is my cesium map code where we create this https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20BIM.html model using cesium but.
But i want to add three js 3D model in this code. suggest me how we can add three js 3D model in this code.
I am using Cesium through npm.

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
      terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
      animation: false,
      timeline: false,
    });
    const scene = viewer.scene;

    viewer.cesiumWidget.creditContainer.parentNode?.removeChild(
      viewer.cesiumWidget.creditContainer);

    viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601(
      "2022-08-01T00:00:00Z"
    );

    const tileset = scene.primitives.add(
      new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
        url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(1240402),
      })
    );

    tileset.readyPromise
      .then(function (tileset: any) {
        viewer.zoomTo(
          tileset,
          new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(
            0.5,
            -0.4,
            tileset.boundingSphere.radius * 4.0
          )
        );
      })
      .catch(function (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    tileset.colorBlendMode = Cesium.Cesium3DTileColorBlendMode.REPLACE;

    let selectedFeature: any;
    let picking = false;

    function setElementColor(element: any, color: any) {
      const featuresToColor = element[element];
      const length = featuresToColor.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        const feature = featuresToColor[i];
        feature.color = Cesium.Color.clone(color, feature.color);
      }
    }


    function selectFeature(feature: any) {
      const element = feature.getProperty("element");
      setElementColor(element, Cesium.Color.YELLOW);
      selectedFeature = feature;
    }

    function unselectFeature(feature: any) {
      if (!Cesium.defined(feature)) {
        return;
      }
      const element = feature.getProperty("element");
      setElementColor(element, Cesium.Color.WHITE);
      if (feature === selectedFeature) {
        selectedFeature = undefined;
      }
    }

    const handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
    handler.setInputAction(function (movement: any) {
      if (!picking) {
        return;
      }

      const feature = scene.pick(movement.endPosition);

      unselectFeature(selectedFeature);

      if (feature instanceof Cesium.Cesium3DTileFeature) {
        selectFeature(feature);
      }
    }, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to add 3D Models to a Cesium view, the simplest way is to use the model format supported by Cesium, which is glTF / GLB.  Various examples show 3D models being loaded into Cesium, for example:

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Models.html

```js
const entity = viewer.entities.add({
    name: url,
    position: position,
    orientation: orientation,
    model: {
        uri: url
    },
});
viewer.trackedEntity = entity;
```

These kinds of models can be created and exported from ThreeJS using the ThreeJS [GLTFExporter](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/exporters/GLTFExporter).  The exported result can then be loaded into Cesium, for example by providing the URL to the code above.

Comment: thank you, can you send some building gITF online URL which I use in this code for testing, and how we can create any building 3D model in glTF file

Comment: Creating a new model is too broad a question for this site, maybe try looking at some online tutorials for Blender or other model-building software.  Cesium does ship with a sample building, a small wooden tower: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/SampleData/models/WoodTower/Wood_Tower.glb